# headless ssh key password from keychain

Tags: password, macos, keychain, ssh, launchd

On MacOS 10.12 Sierra (or/and OS X 10.11 EI Capitan) how can one use the passwords for ssh keys stored in the keychain headless?

If one ssh-es in and left a local session running one can see ssh-agent is available

```
launchctl list | grep ssh
ps ax | grep ssh-agent
```

and can be used by setting SSH_AUTH_SOCK correctly

```
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(ls -t1 /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd*/Listeners | head -n 1 );
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
```

But as soon as the local user logs out the remote session can't use an ssh-agent backed by keychain anymore (no output for the first 2 commands). I tried;

```
sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.openssh.ssh-agent.plist
```

but it fails to help, and

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -l)"
```

fails with `launch_activate_socket(): No such process`, and

```
eval "$(ssh-agent)"
```

fails to connect to the existing socket `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.*/Listeners` instead using `/var/folders/*/*/T/ssh-*/agent.*`.

```
security login-keychain
```

outputs `/Users/*/Library/Keychains/login.keychain-db` regardless.
It might be possible to [trigger a local login](https://superuser.com/questions/39322/induce-mac-graphical-login-from-ssh) but I want to avoid that.

Comment: Did you already find a solution for that?

Comment: @AlexanderRemesch locking the screen instead of logout is the only workaround I know of.